# how to receive timezone in android broadcast receiver call?

Tags: java, android

I do not know how to receive call information (time zone utc gmt ) from the broadcast receiver in Android.. 
can someone help me? 
thanks.

Comment: and we don´t know what you have done so far, so please provide us some relevant code of your project....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know the new timezone in your `ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED` receiver?

Just [check out the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)!

> The intent will have the following extra values:
>    `time-zone` - The `java.util.TimeZone.getID()` value identifying the new time zone.

Example:

```
public class TimeZoneChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        String newTimezoneId = intent.getStringExtra("time-zone"); 
        Log.i("my-app", "Received TIMEZONE_CHANGED, new TZ is \"" + newTimezoneId + "\"");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would to known a timezone or umt or gmt when receive an incoming call in broadcast receiver.

Comment: What about `TimeZone.getDefault()`?

Comment: Yes, but i would receive the timezone of device that exevute the call

Comment: You mean the *caller's timezone*...? This is not possible directly. You could only dissect the phone number and use some kind of list/map to match all kinds of different country and area codes to timezones but even then you can have issues with mobile and service numbers and of course unknown caller IDs (plus it would be quite a complex thing to do).